# If I don't respect the java package naming convention, the .class cannot be found by the command "java", right?

Tags: java, classpath, package, naming

Is it normal that "java Hello3" (with Hello3.class a java class) gives me:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Hello3 (wrong name: pp/Hello3)
```

Hello3.class is the compiled binary of Hello3.java. This java file is declared to be under some package "pp", but it is not put in the "pp" directory.

```
package pp;
public class Hello3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

My command java Hello3.java is done at the same directory as Hello3.java. What's more, even the command "java -cp . Hello3" doesnot work! Maybe a problem from mine??

Since I got your confirmation from the following answers, I may draw a naive conclusion here: it's too easy to make a .class that never works. Simply declare your .java under package XXX but do not put it in the directory XXX.  IMHO, I think this can be used as an attack!

Comment: It looks like correct behavior. Class has its package stored internally and won't work if it's in incorrect directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You indeed need to have Hello3.class in a directory named `pp`. The directory containing `pp` should be in the classpath. Suppose this directory is called `classes`:

```
...
  |_ classes
         |_ pp
            |_ Hello3.class
```

The command to launch your Java program should thus be

```
java -cp /the/path/to/classes pp.Hello3
```

or, on Windows

```
java -cp c:\the\path\to\classes pp.Hello3
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is normal. Public Java classes must be in a directory which agrees with the package name.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `java -cp <path_to_classpath_libs> pp.Hello3` and the Hello3.java & Hello3.class files must be under a `pp` directory as directed by the package declaration.